# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (is there anything wrong with this Oracle procedure?)

Tags: oracle, plsql

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Check my Oracle procedure...is there anything wrong?

Procedure shows error:

```
-- subjectwise record display
DECLARE 
s_id attendence.student_idstudent%type; 
s_present number(3); 
CURSOR student_present is select student_idstudent, count(student_idstudent) from attendence where status like 'Present' and student_subject_subjectid like 102 group by student_idstudent;

s1_id attendence.student_idstudent%type; 
s1_total number(3); 
CURSOR student_total is select student_idstudent, count(student_idstudent) from attendence where student_subject_subjectid like 102 group by student_idstudent;

BEGIN 
OPEN student_present; 
OPEN student_total;
LOOP 
FETCH student_present into s_id, s_present;
FETCH student_total into s1_id, s1_total;
EXIT WHEN student_present%notfound;  
dbms_output.put_line('student '|| s_id || ' has ' ||S_present/s1_total*100 || '% record' ); 
END LOOP; 

CLOSE student_present; 
CLOSE student_total; 

END; 
/


--

CREATE PROCEDURE make is
c        NUMBER(4);
c1       NUMBER(4);
CURSOR cur1 IS SELECT student_idstudent, count(CASE WHEN  status = 'Present'  then 1 END)/count(*)*100 as percentage FROM attendence where student_subject_subjectid = 102 group by student_idstudent;
BEGIN
execute immediate 'truncate table myatt';
OPEN cur1;
LOOP
FETCH cur1 into c,c1;
EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;
insert into myatt values(c,c1);
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
END make;
/
```

Comment: Both look fine to me. What and how are you calling the code that gives you the error? Also, where are you running this code? Is it in something like Toad or SQL Developer?

Comment: This code not executed in netbeans ide. Project Name is : Attendance Management System java

Comment: You have to show us how you are calling this procedure into your Java code. Also the `dbms_output.put_line` function was not designed to be used on a third part language as java, it is meant to be used inside oracle clients only where you can configure the output and show it.

Comment: And on which line is it saying there is an invalid SQL statement?

Comment: sql ="BEGIN\n"
            + "make;\n"
            + "END;\n";
    pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.execute();
    String sql1 = "select * from attendance";
    UpdateJTable(sql1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);